# Prepend spaces to text if too short

Tags: bash, notepad++, text-alignment

I have two sets of text files that I need to prepend spaces to until each line or piece of text is 4 characters in length.

The first set of text files look like this:

```
0,
0,
0,
0,
0,
0,
251,
251,
251,
0,
0,
0,
0,
12,
12,
12,
```

I want to add spaces at the start of each line until all of them are 4 characters long.

The second set looks like this:

```
0, 0, 0, 251, 251, 251, 0, 0, 0, 0, 12, 12, 12,
0, 0, 251, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 12, 12, 12, 12, 0,
```

In this case, I need to check if there are 4 characters between every 2 commas and, if not, prepend spaces until there is.

I am looking for a way to do this preferably with either Notepad++ or shell scripting. Otherwise, any other good ways of doing it would also be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a [Stack Snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). See How to create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It also very helpful to show in your Question an expected result, and quote any (exact) errors you are getting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first task can be accomplished by `printf`:

```
while read line ; do
    printf '%4s\n' "$line"
done < lines.txt
```

Similarly for the second case, but using an array instead of a scalar variable

```
while read -a numbers ; do
    printf '%5s' "${numbers[@]}"
    echo
done < numbers.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

If the first snippet is in a file named `text1` and the second's in a file named `text2`:

For the first set, you could do:

```sh
$ awk '{ printf("%3d,\n", $0) }' text1 # It'd be more modular to get the left-pad whitespace count in awk
  0,
  0,
  0,
  0,
  0,
  0,
251,
251,
251,
  0,
  0,
  0,
  0,
 12,
 12,
 12,
```

For the second,

```sh
$ column -t text2
0,  0,  0,    251,  251,  251,  0,  0,  0,   0,   12,  12,  12,
0,  0,  251,  0,    0,    0,    0,  0,  12,  12,  12,  12,  0,
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but your second command doesn't answer the question I asked. I'm looking for exactly 4 characters between each comma whereas your answer is lining up the first digit of each row instead.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
   for i in $(cat bashdata.txt);do printf "%03d,\n" "${i::-2}";done
```

It basically pipes the data into printf and format according to your requirements

[image: output]

To append simply space, remove the 0 in printf as such:

```
for i in $(cat bashdata.txt);do printf "%3d,\n" "${i::-2}";done
```

[image: output2]

Comment: Thanks but I'm not trying to add leading 0s to each number. I'm trying to add leading spaces. `"%3d,\n"` would have done it.